# Insert new DIV between two DIVs that have the same class and are immediate siblings

Tags: jquery, find, append, jquery-selectors

Struggling with this one for a while now. My markup simplified:

```
<div class=row>
    <div class="somediv"></div>
    <div class="somediv2"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="somediv3"></div>
    <div class="somediv4"></div>
<div class=row>
....
```

I need to find a way to select all DIVs on document ready that:
  1. has a class: elem
  2. their next DIV also has the class name: elem.
Then I need to insert a new DIV between them:

```
<div class=row>
    <div class="somediv2"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="new"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="somediv3"></div>
    <div class="somediv4"></div>
<div class=row> // and it goes...


$(document).ready( function () {
   if($('.elem').next().hasClass('.elem')) {
       $('<div class="new"></div>').appendTo().prev('.elem');
   } else {
   });
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   $('.elem + .elem').before($('<div class="new"></div>'));
});
```

It's using CSS's adjacent sibling selector (`+`). It finds an element with class `.elem` with another element with class `.elem` immediately preceding it, then adds a new div before it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4r2k4/

Comment: okay - I like your answer better than mine! http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/kvg8N/1/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddles. I forgot to mention (sorry) that the html is generated by javascript. Your codes are working and is simply to understand on a regular page, but I guess because of the generated content this is not working for me. When I'm using click event, I simply add live() to the function, how can do something similar in this case?

Comment: It's working if I attach it to a click event in the above mentioned environment.

Comment: I think you may want to post a new question to get the answer to the .live part. I think the answer is going to end up looking more like your original code and less like Matt's elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you guys. Attaching it a live click event is perfect in my case.

Answer (score 3):

The non-jQuery solution:

```
var divs, str;

divs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'elem' );

[].slice.call( divs ).forEach(function ( div ) {
    str = ' ' + div.nextElementSibling.className + ' ';
    if ( str.indexOf( ' elem ' ) !== -1 ) {
        div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterend', ' <div class="new">X</div> ' );
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2MfgB/2/

*"But Šime, this doesn't work in IE8..."* `:P`

---

**Update:**
Alternative solution:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll( '.elem + .elem' );

[].slice.call( divs ).forEach(function ( div ) {
    div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforebegin', ' <div class="new">X</div> ' );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2MfgB/3/

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks pretty good to me. Don't you just need to wrap it in a `each` so that it fires on each one?

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   $('.elem').each( function() {
     if($(this).next().hasClass('.elem')) {
         $('<div class="new"></div>').appendTo().prev('.places');
     } else {}
   });
});
```